# The unitarity of the $\delta(x)$ potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, dirac-delta-distributions, unitarity

One of the common potentials to solve in quantum mechanics is when $$H=\frac{p^{2}}{2m}+\delta(x).$$ Is this Hamiltonian considered to produce unitary evolution?
In particular, I'm not sure what is the meaning of a unitary time evolution with a distribution, which here is given by $$\exp\left[-i\,\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt\,\left(\frac{p^{2}}{2m}+\delta(x)\right)\right].$$

Comment: That Hamiltonian is not an operator in a Hilbert space but in a distributional extension of a Hilbert space which is a part of a rigged Hilbert space. There is no "norm preservation" here.

Comment: @DanielC: Right. So, do you agree that this evolution is, in fact, not unitary?

Comment: DanielC:  even if I remove the delta function, but use an unbounded phase space the same problem will still occur, right?

Comment: First, I don't understand why you write the time evolution with that integral. Nothing depends on $t$, so that reduces to $$\exp [i(t-t_0)H].$$ Second, I don't believe that this time evolution is non-unitary. The Hamiltonian $H$ is singular, but it is still real-valued, so it is self-adjoint (formally at least). The usual computation thus shows $$ \frac{d}{dt} \int \left\lvert  e^{itH}\psi\right\rvert^2\, dx =0, $$ again formally. The mathematical difficulty is give a meaning to $e^{itH}$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro The time evolution that you wrote is equivalent to mine, but note that this has no Taylor series expansion (as in the case that the Hamiltonian is given by a function), and I cannot see how to act with a dagger properly on such a construction. I also don't think that the last integral that you wrote is going to be differentiable on the singular point.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro For example, this is the way in which we establish unitarity for the case of a bounded Hamiltonian $$\left(\exp\left[-i\hat{H}\right]\right)^{\dagger}\,=\,\left(\boldsymbol{\hat{1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-i\hat{H})^{n}}{n!}\right)^{\dagger}\,=\,\boldsymbol{\hat{1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(i\hat{H})^{n}}{n!}\,=\,\left(\exp\left[i\hat{H}\right]\right)^{-1}.$$ Obviously, these steps are no longer valid in the case above anymore.

Comment: @Yair: "...these steps are no longer valid in the case above anymore". Why not? That's exactly the point of my previous comment. Formally at least, $\hat H^\dagger=\hat H$. This is what I meant when I wrote that $H$ is formally self-adjoint. From that, unitarity follows by whatever method you prefer. To reiterate, I believe that $e^{itH}$ is still a unitary operator. The mathematical difficulty is to identify the domain of $H$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Clearly, the conditions for Taylor expansion does not apply for an exponent involving delta function (the construction is not differentiable). Also, the conjugate of a delta function has to be *defined* equal to the standard delta, but this is not something that can be shown at the singular point (as in the case of ordinary complex numbers). There is more than one way to consistently define the conjugate of a delta function. If we put the 'formal treatment' aside and stick to rigorious mathematical prespective, it seems to me that there is a problem with the claim of unitarity.

Comment: @DanielC: Is there any way to get in touch with you? one of the moderators told me that you are the suitable person to ask..